# cordova-plugin-googlemaps でマーカ画像の変更ができない

Tags: cordova, google-maps

cordova でアプリ開発をしています．
cordova-plugin-googlemaps というプラグインを使用しています．
マーカーのアイコン画像の変更をしたく，下記のようなコードを書きました．

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
// Get the current device location "without map"
var option = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true // use GPS as much as possible
};
plugin.google.maps.LocationService.getMyLocation(option, function(location) {

  // Create a map with the device location
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv, {
    'camera': {
      target: location.latLng,
      zoom: 16
    }
  });


  // Add a marker
  var marker = map.addMarker({
    'title': 'I am here',
    'position': location.latLng,
    'icon': 'icon.png',
  });

  //marker.showInfoWindow();

});
});
```

画像のパスは間違っていないのですが，表示がデフォルトの赤マーカのままです．

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/143117

Comment: cordova-plugin-googlemapsのバージョンは何ですか？　version 2.4.1が最新版ですので、それで試してみていただけますか。

Comment: 2.4.0です。帰ったら試そうかと思います！

Comment: バージョンは関係ないようでした．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドキュメントを見ると指定でurlプロパティを持ったオブジェクトにすると良さそうです。

```
  // Add a marker
  var marker = map.addMarker({
    'title': 'I am here',
    'position': location.latLng,
    'icon': { 'url': 'icon.png' }
  });
```

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.3.0/class/Marker/README.md#icon

Comment: >'icon' : {'url' : 'icon. png'}

Comment: ＞画像のパスは間違っていないのですが，表示がデフォルトの赤マーカのままです．　大嘘でした．　てっきりJavaScriptから見た位置かと勘違いしていたのですが実際はHTMLファイルから見た位置でした．　``'icon': { 'url': 'icon.png' }``
このような書き方ができることが知れたので，ベストアンサーにいたします．ほかにもサイズとか指定できるみたいです．